# Exception caught : System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODB C SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to create a odbc for MSSQL and when i am running my exe through cmd i am getting this error:

C SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the o
Memberships', database 'MatOrtho', schema 'dbo'.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, Re
etcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior be
 String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odb
hod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior be
 String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior
   at ManagedClass.fnValidateUser(String strEmail, String strPassword, St
trUserId) in d:\Mat_Ortho\matortho\service_layer\ServerService\MsdnAccess

Comment: You have to post your code. We can't see your computer.

Comment: The error message indicates that you don't have read(select) right on the table/schema you are querying. If you have the admin right on your sqlserver, you can [grant right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx) by yourself. Otherwise, you will need some help from the admin of your target database.

Comment: Looks like the login you are using to connect with doesn't have permission to SELECT from the table you are trying to read.